# Get object from .readEntity

Tags: java, json, jersey, deserialization

I have a java service which calls an API and gets the following in return

```
{
  "status": {
    "service1": {
      "available": true,
      ...
    },
    "service2": {
      "available": false,
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

How can i use `.readEntity` (or something else) to get the object for a given field; say `service2`

Or just convert all objects inside `status` to a `List<>` of objects

`String output = response.readEntity(String.class);` works, but i dont know how to parse it properly to something useful as i dont want to search in the string

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

Response response = client
        .target(url)
        .request()
        .get();

String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: You need to tell us which libraries you are using at a minimum. Preferably, construct a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can model the data with a POJO and use that to extract the data. A model of the JSON that you've posted might look something like

```java
public static class ResponseData {
    private Map<String, Service> status;

    // getters and setters

    public static class Service {
        private boolean available;

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

The getters and setters should use [JavaBean naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions). Then make sure you have a JSON provider such as Jackson

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can simply pass the POJO class to the `readEntity()` method and it will deserialize the JSON into your POJO class.

```java
ResponseData resData = res.readEntity(ResponseData.class);
Service service2 = resData.getStatus().get("service2");
```

For more details on modeling your JSON, you can do a Google search for "data binding with Jackson"